# Python C# - Unicode character is not the same on Python and C#

Tags: c#, python, unicode

I encountered with a problem while working on text files. I found that the character Unicode representation on `Python` and `C#` is different.

While opening the file with `Python 3.5.2` on specific index the unicode character is:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
     text = f.read()
text[189]

// Output: u"\U0001F464"
```

While opening the file with `C#` on the same index this char is represented by two characters:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(((int)text[189]).ToString("X4")); 

// Output: "D83D"

string text = File.ReadAllText("file.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
Console.WriteLine(((int)text[190]).ToString("X4")); 

// Output: "DC64"
```

So on python this char is on index 189 and on c# its on 189 and 190.

Reference to this charecter on fileformat website:

> http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F464/index.htm

As you can see there, the representation of this charecter has a different length. On C#/C/C++/Java "\uD83D\uDC64" and on python u"\U0001F464".

The part of the text that is problematic:

> Sign in

Is there a way to use the same unicode representation in Python 3.5 and C#?

**Edit:**

Download of the original file in which this error happend:
https://ufile.io/pr5v6

Comment: "*As you can see there, the representation of this charecter has a different length. On C#/C/C++/Java 2 chars and on python 1 char*" not true, I think you need to read on what *UTF-8* is and then fix the problem where it actually happens, which is not while opening the file. Refer to the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to understand why I say this.

Comment: You can try it yourself. I checked it enough times before i posted it. I will be adding the original file in a second.

Comment: You would be surprised by the fact that "*checking*" code and verifying that it "*works*" in general doesn't really mean that it does.

Comment: Related reading : [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't fix it.  It is inherent in the Unicode implementation of the languages.

When reading a file and decoding to Unicode, C# and Java store Unicode strings internally encoded as [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).  Code points outside the [basic multilingual plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (BMP, U+0000 to U+FFFF) use [surrogates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates) (two words) to represent a Unicode code point.  The fact that you can see a Unicode code point as two words is a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).

Python 3.3+ hides this abstraction.  It internally uses 1-, 2- or 4-byte encodings as needed to represent a Unicode string, but presents only the Unicode code points to the user.

Python 2 (same leaky abstraction as C# and Java):

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> len(u'\U0001F464')
2
>>> u'\U0001F464'[0]
u'\ud83d'
>>> u'\U0001F464'[1]
u'\udc64'
```

Python 3.3+:

```
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> len(u'\U0001F464')
1
>>> u'\U0001F464'[0]
''
```

Internally, Python 3 uses UTF-32 to store a Unicode string containing a non-BMP code point and would use four bytes to store U+1F464.