# String lengths differ in Python3 from file and through copy-and-paste

Tags: c#, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have a string like this from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyre,_Lebanon)

Tyre (Arabic: صور‎‎, Ṣūr; Phoenician: , Ṣur; Hebrew: צוֹר‎, Tsor; Tiberian Hebrew צֹר‎, Ṣōr; Akkadian: , Ṣurru; Greek: Τύρος, Týros; Turkish: Sur; Latin: Tyrus, Armenian Տիր [Dir]), sometimes romanized as Sour, is a city in the South Governorate of Lebanon.

**When this sentence is loaded from a file, its length is 262. When it is copied and pasted from Browser, it is 267.**

My question is that I have an existing data pipeline in C# that recognizes the length as 266 (the copy-and-paste length above but default read-from-file in C#), but Python3 reads the C# text output file and considers it as length of 262. The issue is that the character indexing (e.g. s[10:20]) through these two encoding systems will be different and make the end-to-end algorithm fails at this type of cases.

It appears the underlying encoding is different, though they have the same appearance to human readers (only the different parts shown):

- Phoenician: \xf0\x90\xa4\x91\xf0\x90\xa4\x85\xf0\x90\xa4\x93, \xe1\xb9\xa2ur;
- Phoenician: \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd, \xe1\xb9\xa2ur;

And

- Akkadian: \xf0\x92\x80\xab\xf0\x92\x8a\x92, \xe1\xb9\xa2urru;
- Akkadian: \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd, \xe1\xb9\xa2urru;

**Is there a way for Python to read the file using the later encoding of length 266? And how to detect/determine the proper encoding system from the utf-8 bytes above?**

The full utf-8 encoding for each case is shown below for further investigation

#### From file

b'Tyre (Arabic: \xd8\xb5\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xe2\x80\x8e\xe2\x80\x8e, \xe1\xb9\xa2\xc5\xabr; Phoenician: \xf0\x90\xa4\x91\xf0\x90\xa4\x85\xf0\x90\xa4\x93, \xe1\xb9\xa2ur; Hebrew: \xd7\xa6\xd7\x95\xd6\xb9\xd7\xa8\xe2\x80\x8e, Tsor; Tiberian Hebrew \xd7\xa6\xd6\xb9\xd7\xa8\xe2\x80\x8e, \xe1\xb9\xa2\xc5\x8dr; Akkadian: \xf0\x92\x80\xab\xf0\x92\x8a\x92, \xe1\xb9\xa2urru; Greek: \xce\xa4\xcf\x8d\xcf\x81\xce\xbf\xcf\x82, T\xc3\xbdros; Turkish: Sur; Latin: Tyrus, Armenian \xd5\x8f\xd5\xab\xd6\x80 [Dir]), sometimes romanized as Sour, is a city in the South Governorate of Lebanon.'

#### From copy and paste

b'Tyre (Arabic: \xd8\xb5\xd9\x88\xd8\xb1\xe2\x80\x8e\xe2\x80\x8e, \xe1\xb9\xa2\xc5\xabr; Phoenician: \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd, \xe1\xb9\xa2ur; Hebrew: \xd7\xa6\xd7\x95\xd6\xb9\xd7\xa8\xe2\x80\x8e, Tsor; Tiberian Hebrew \xd7\xa6\xd6\xb9\xd7\xa8\xe2\x80\x8e, \xe1\xb9\xa2\xc5\x8dr; Akkadian: \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd, \xe1\xb9\xa2urru; Greek: \xce\xa4\xcf\x8d\xcf\x81\xce\xbf\xcf\x82, T\xc3\xbdros; Turkish: Sur; Latin: Tyrus, Armenian \xd5\x8f\xd5\xab\xd6\x80 [Dir]), sometimes romanized as Sour, is a city in the South Governorate of Lebanon.'

Comment: My guess is that Python and Javascript have different ideas about which codepoints get combined into a single character.

Comment: `b'\xef\xbf\xbd'` (which you have repeated a few times in these two examples) is the UTF-8 encoding of the replacement character ("�"). This character is often used for displaying invalid bytes in UTF-8, but apparently your browser substitutes some characters it doesn't want to deal with (for whatever reason). I'm pretty sure the version with the replacement characters is broken; now you need to find out why this happens in your C# pipeline.

Comment: @Beefster As long as there is a way to enforce the encoding, it should be consistent. Is there anyway like that?

Comment: @Beefster Javascript? Why Javascript?

Comment: @lenz or just the browser. Either way.

Comment: @Beefster It behaves the same for any copy and paste on Windows. Same behavior in C#.

Comment: Another observation: the scrambled characters are exactly the ones that lie outside the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane). And each Phoenitian/Akkadian character is replaced by two replacement characters. Since characters beyond the BMP require two surrogate characters in UTF16 (which is used internally throughout Microsoft software, I think), this is suspicious. Maybe you should search information on the topic of C# support for non-BMP characters.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have Phoenician fonts installed in your system, so the web browser (as @lenz mentioned in the comment) displays characters  instead. Python loads your string properly.

There are 5 problematic characters in the text: 3 Phoenician and 2 Akkadian:

- The first character of the problematic part with Phoenician symbols is *'Phoenician Letter Sade'* (https://unicode-table.com/en/10911/) -- it spans **4 bytes** in UTF-8:    F0 90 A4 91
- It is followed with *'Phoenician Letter Wau'* (https://unicode-table.com/en/10905/) -- again **4 bytes**: F0 90 A4 85
- The third letter if *'Phoenician Letter Rosh'* (https://unicode-table.com/en/10913/) -- is uses **4 bytes** as well: F0 90 A4 93

(I omit the Akkadian ones.)

Each of those letters is replaced in your encodings by `\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd` that correspond to `��`.

Each problematic letter somehow gets replaced by two `�` signs, so the total length of the string increases by 5, from 262 to 267 characters.

Comment: There are no characters that are 6 bytes long in UTF-8. `\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd` encodes "��". The count of 267 characters (not bytes!) comes from the fact that each of the five characters was interpreted as two characters. The question is: **Why does this also happen when reading from file** (not only when copy-pasting from the browser)?

Comment: Well, the question stated above is different :) To answer your new question we should probably take a look at the source code...
(I will edit my answer using your comment to make it correct.)

Comment: You are right, I was leaping ahead of the original question. I have the impression that the OP is trying to solve the wrong end of the problem (trying to get Python do the same mistakes as said C# pipeline).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I found a different viewpoint to answer this question. C# does report longer length of a string, but it does not mean it is incorrect, just the underlying encoding system is different and has its limitation.

http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2010/04/i18n-comparing-character-encoding-in-c.html

[Python C# - Unicode character is not the same on Python and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963954/python-c-sharp-unicode-character-is-not-the-same-on-python-and-c-sharp)

> When reading a file and decoding to Unicode, C# and Java store Unicode strings internally encoded as UTF-16. Code points outside the basic multilingual plane (BMP, U+0000 to U+FFFF) use surrogates (two words) to represent a Unicode code point. The fact that you can see a Unicode code point as two words is a leaky abstraction.
>
> Python 3.3+ hides this abstraction. It internally uses 1-, 2- or 4-byte encodings as needed to represent a Unicode string, but presents only the Unicode code points to the user.

This explains that why the lengths reported by C# can be longer than Python.

How to make them congruent? hmmm... probably not directly but through a substring search as a post-processing...