# Transform c sharp code to python : unicode divide

Tags: c#, python-3.x

I want to copy this code which is in csharp into python. It seems that unicode operation as divide is allowed in csharp but not in python.

The two lines which annoy me are these :

```
    int num2 = ch / '\x0010';
    int num3 = ch % '\x0010';
```

I found this post which tells that unicode is different in python and csharp but does not provide any solution.

-> [Python C# - Unicode character is not the same on Python and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963954/python-c-sharp-unicode-character-is-not-the-same-on-python-and-c-sharp)

i tried to cast the unicode to bytes and then to int but it does not show relevant results. I tried that as char in csharp is a unicode character in utf-16 which does not have a similar type in python.

Here is the full code I want to transform :

```
string Key = 'toto';
string Password = 'titi';
char[] chArray = new char[] {
                   'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
                   'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
                   'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
                   'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', '_'};
string str = "#1";
for (int i = 0; i < Password.Length; i++)
{
    char ch = Password[i];
    char ch2 = Key[i];
    int num2 = ch / '\x0010';
    int num3 = ch % '\x0010';
    int index = (num2 + ch2) % chArray.Length;
    int num5 = (num3 + ch2) % chArray.Length;
    str = str + chArray[index] + chArray[num5];
}
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

in my example the final result ( var str ) should be : #174147414

And step by step the values num2;num3 are :

```
7;4
6;9
7;4
6;9
```

Do you have any idea how to achieve my goal?

Sorry for the english syntax.

Thanks for reading

Comment: num2 = ord(ch) // ord('\u0010') is what you are looking at? beware \x0010 equal to "\010" in python which is three-character string first character is a null terminator. So Unicode character 0010 should be present as "\u0010" which looks like an issue on your end,

Comment: Thanks so much that work

Really find nothing about ord. 

Set it as solved :)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is inappropriate here to add [SOLVED] to the title or to edit the solution into the question. If you've found a solution and want to share it, you can do so by writing an answer below - see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information. If you don't want to do that, you can either leave the question as is and hope someone else writes that answer or you can delete the question using the link below the tags.

Comment: Coder un bot c'est mal

Comment: C'est son utilisation qui en est mauvaise ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provide by @Abdurrahim worked : 
num2 = ord(ch) // ord('\u0010')

Because :  \x0010 equal to "\010" in python